# Invoke REST api and insert details into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc

I've a requirement. I have a REST API using `spring-mvc` in which there is a POST method to insert data into MySQL database. I checked it through postman client and results got inserted into `MySQL` database. Now I've one more spring project say **InsertMongo** in which the details are inserted into `MONGODB` as documents. So, i need to invoke my REST API in that spring project **InsertMongo** such that i have to insert the details into `MySQL` table instead of inserting them into `MySQL`. Let's say I've all the details which are to be inserted . So, how can i send them as body to `POST` call and how can i invoke my post call here. can anybody tell me how to proceed. I'm not getting any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "insert the details into mysql table instead of inserting them into mysql"? huh?

Comment: yes. Insert them into mysql